# Iphone App doesn't start after launch, though it worked now for days

Tags: ios, iphone

I've created a simple Iphone App with Objective C and tested it on my Phone.

After the installation the App works fine for several days. Then all of a sudden the app won't start after launch. It just shows a white screen for 1 second and closes after.

Is there any way to find out what causes this crash? I already connected my phone to Itunes and tried to find the crashlog. There was no crashlog though in the supposed folder.

Do you guys have any tips for me how to find the issue? I've already searched the internet without any success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: getting issue in iPhone only or simulator too ?

Comment: The simulator runs fine. Though i can't test it for the same duration. I mean it just occurs after several days. 

Could there be some issuses with my development license?

Comment: `Though i can't test it for the same duration` explain, may it is.

Comment: Well it seems to just expire. 

Maybe I need a developer account.

Comment: then inside targets > build settings > code signing just select dont code sign, rest you need developer acc.

Answer (score 0):

Open the app in Xcode, attach your iPhone and let Xcode run it on your iPhone

Comment: As I said, the App works just fine on Xcode and the Iphone. 
This issue occurs after running the app successfully on my Iphone for several days.

Comment: ah.. I thought you ment it didn't worked anymore since.. Perhaps you can implement Crashlytics into your app.. [http://fabric.io]

Answer (score 0):

If I were on your position, I will see the storyboard. 
First, the project has connected with storyboard. 
Second, storyboard has entry point to start the controller.

Please click project in tree, click general tab / Deployment Info/ Main Interface.
If there was no storyboard name, your project can be crashed.

I just tested something when I type incorrect storyboard name to main interface, it shows crash.

Comment: I really don't understand, what you mean. Sorry. :(

Comment: can you share your project? I can help you.